# HTML Range element changes CSS filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

Here are my image and range elements. When a file image is chosen, it will be displayed, then I want to change its brightness via range value. But it does not respond to value change. I try logging CSS filter property and it always returns `none`

```
<body>
    <input type="range" id="myRange" value="100" max="200" min="0">
    <input type="file" id="myImg">
    <br>
    <img src="#" id="image">
    <div id="demo">1</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#myRange").change(function(){
            var brightness=$(this).val();
            $("#demo").html(brightness+"%");
            console.log(brightness);
            $("#image").css("filter","brightness("+brightness+"%)");
            console.log($("#image").css("filter"));
        });
        $("#myImg").change(function(){
            if (this.files && this.files[0]){
                var reader=new FileReader();
                reader.onload=function(e){
                    $("#image").attr("src",e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

jQuery is already included
Help me please. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution myself. What I need is

```
$("#image").css({
   "filter":"brightness("+brightness+"%)",
   "webkitFilter":"brightness("+brightness+"%)",
   "mozFilter":"brightness("+brightness+"%)",
   "oFilter":"brightness("+brightness+"%)",
   "msFilter":"brightness("+brightness+"%)"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine in my [PEN HERE](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/PGpjmX?editors=1111)

Also the snippet below is working great. I would first try to relocate your `<script>` to the head, if not, you may try including an external JS file.

```js
    $("#myRange").change(function() {
  var brightness = $(this).val();
  $("#demo").html(brightness + "%");
  console.log(brightness);
  $("#image").css("filter", "brightness(" + brightness + "%)");
  console.log($("#image").css("filter"));
});
$("#myImg").change(function() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $("#image").attr("src", e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <input type="range" id="myRange" value="100" max="200" min="0">
  <input type="file" id="myImg">
  <br>
  <img src="#" id="image">
  <div id="demo">1</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It does not work, neither on Codepen nor Snippet. It just logs the `brightness` variable, the `filter` attribute is still `none`

Comment: Duh, then it's your browser compatibility. If I say it works for me, then it probably works, and you should debug further and realize compatibility.